# Points not showing in Map using TimeStampedGeojson Folium Plugin

Tags: folium

I followed https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Plugins.ipynb to create my own map using TimeStampedGeojson folium Plugin, Time slider is working but points aren't getting displayed on map. I have using pune city coordinates , the aim was to display multipoint coordinates with changing icon and popup with timeslider functionality over a month.

```
points = [
{
    'time': '2019-09-01',
    'popup': '<h1>address1</h1>',
    'coordinates': [18.528387, 73.874251]
},
{
    'time': '2019-09-02',
    'popup': '<h1>address1</h1>',
    'coordinates': [18.456863, 73.801601]
},
{
    'time': '2019-09-03',
    'popup':'<h1>address1</h1>',
    'coordinates': [18.527615, 73.872384]
},
{
    'time': '2019-09-04',
    'popup': '<h1>address1</h1>',
    'coordinates': [18.528387, 73.874251]},
{
    'time': '2019-09-05',
    'popup': '<h1>address1</h1>',
    'coordinates': [18.456863, 73.801601]}]
features = [
{
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'Point',
        'coordinates': point['coordinates'],
    },
    'properties': {
        'time': point['time'],
        'popup': point['popup']
    }
} for point in points]

features.append(
{
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'LineString',
        'coordinates':[
            [18.528387, 73.874251],
            [18.456863, 73.801601],
            [18.527615, 73.872384],
            [18.528387, 73.874251],
            [18.456863, 73.801601]
        ] ,
    },
    'properties': {
        'popup': 'Current address',
        'times': [
            '2019-09-01',
            '2019-09-02',
            '2019-09-03',
            '2019-09-04',
            '2019-09-05'
        ]
    }
})
m = folium.Map(
location=[18.5204,73.8567],
tiles='cartodbpositron',
zoom_start=10,)

plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
{
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': features
},
auto_play=False,
loop=False,
#max_speed=1,
loop_button=True,
date_options='YYYY/MM/DD',
#time_slider_drag_update=True,
duration='P2D').add_to(m)
```

[This is the output of code in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2sfe.png)

Answer (score 1):

The locations are getting rendered on the map, try zooming out the map's current view. I suspect the issue is with incorrect order of lat/long positions given inside your *coordinates* var.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Saved a lot of time-yeah the issue was reverse order of lat/long positions, though there wasn't mention of this on folium plugins page- https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html

Comment: Glad I could help ^_^